# django 1.8.5 : “TemplateDoesNotExist” error

Tags: django

I am a beginner in django and I know that there are simillar questions with solutions on stackoverflow ,but the solutions aren't working for me,or I am unable to understand them. This is my settings.py file. Cannot figure out what is wrong with this due to which I am getting the "TemplateDoesNotExist at /rango/ " error.

```
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    TEMPLATE_PATH=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
    TEMPLATE_DIRS=((TEMPLATE_PATH,'templates'),)

    SECRET_KEY = '+za_-(=00o_qbgv4&$9#%i96p9j2$!i6bznqp)0yls3mwjd43s'

    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'rango',
   )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'tango_with_django_project.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tango_with_django_project.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request,'rango/index.html')
```

Comment: You have left the template DIRS setting empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your template settings, **'APP_DIRS':True**, means that Django will search through your app's directory looking for a **'templates'** folder. Therefore, inside your **rango** app folder create a directory **templates/rango/** and ensure your **index.html** is inside that folder.

Alternatively, if your **templates** folder is somewhere else, put the full path to your templates directory in TEMPLATE settings '**DIRS': [/full/path/to/templates/folder]**

Comment: Although its working fine now, but why do I still get this warning on my terminal                                                                                                                                WARNINGS:
    ?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were      deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.

Comment: Its just a warning, the TEMPLATES_DIR declared in your setting is deprecated in Django 1.8. Remove it. You only need the TEMPLATES dictionary